HtmlAgilityPack HtmlWeb().Load(fullUrl) not load every time throw exception Object reference not set to an instance of an object
I am scrapping data from below url but some time its throw Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception on htmlweb.load
`string fullUrl="https://thehiddenbay.com/search/abcd/1/99/0";
HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlWeb().Load(fullUrl);
`
please guide me how can i get correct data every time.
I have try HtmlWeb.LoadFromWebAsync method as well but same result.
